# Problems with storing data into database using angularjs and spring boot

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

This is what i have:

user.java

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column
    private String username;

    @Column
    private String password;

    @Column
    private String lastname;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repo;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public User addUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        return repo.saveAndFlush(user);
    }
```

user.service.js

note: here that the console output the 3 values of username,password and lastname.

```
    function Create(user) {

        console.log(user.username)
        console.log(user.password)
        console.log(user.lastName)


        return $http.post('/user', user).then(handleSuccess, handleError('Error creating user'));
    }
```

registration.controller

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('RegisterController', RegisterController);

    RegisterController.$inject = ['UserService', '$location', '$rootScope', 'FlashService'];
    function RegisterController(UserService, $location, $rootScope, FlashService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.register = register;

        function register() {
            vm.dataLoading = true;
            UserService.Create(vm.user)
                .then(function (response) {
                    if (response.success) {
                        FlashService.Success('Registration successful', true);
                        $location.path('/login');

                    } else {
                        FlashService.Error(response.message);
                        vm.dataLoading = false;
                    }
                });
        }
    }

})();
```

registration.html

```
<div class="container" ng-controller="RegisterController as vm">
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h2>Register</h2>
    <div ng-show="vm.error" class="alert alert-danger">{{vm.error}}</div>
    <form name="form" ng-submit="vm.register()" role="form">


        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.lastName.$dirty && form.lastName.$error.required }">
            <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.lastName" required />
            <span ng-show="form.lastName.$dirty && form.lastName.$error.required" class="help-block">Last name is required</span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required }">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.username" required />
            <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required }">
            <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.password" required />
            <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" ng-disabled="form.$invalid || vm.dataLoading" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            <img ng-if="vm.dataLoading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
            <a href="#/login" class="btn btn-link">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

But for some reason this is the outcome of the user.

```
{id: 1, username: "33", password: "33", lastname: null}
id: 1
lastname: null
password: "33"
username: "33"
```

No matter what i do it keeps saying null. And i really don't know what i'm missing

Does anyone has a clue on this. I think i keep overlooking something.

Comment: `lastName` != `lastname`. Your property names don't match.

Comment: i have been looking for 2 hours.. But something else occurs it says bad sql grammar last_name not define. So i change the name lastname to last_name but where does this come from...

Comment: Change the field on the client from `lastName` to `lastName` don't change the one on the server. (Or specify the name of the column in the `@Column` annotation).

Comment: thanks i got it now. I never going to forget to dubble check the property now !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view and service specify the data for lastname as lastName, your model is in lowercase.

Comment: i have been looking for 2 hours.. But something else occurs it says bad sql grammar last_name not define. So i change the name lastname to last_name but where does this come from...

Comment: Sounds like you didn't change it in the database accordingly.